# Simulating the impact of non-IID data on a model

Tags: modeling, simulation, independence, iid

I have data that is non-IID, and I want to estimate if the dependence is bad enough that it will have a noticeable effect on a fitted classifier. I don't think the exact model type will matter in this case, but for argument's sake let's say I'm using elastic-net logistic regression. In this case the dependence takes the form of clustering among observations, in that if $Y_k = 1$ has a high probability then the probability that $Y_j = 1$ is very low for all $j\neq k$ within the data cluster.

Ideally, I would like to be able to compare the fitted model from the non-IID data set to a "comparable" or "similar" IID data set. So I'm thinking I could just simulate such a data set, fit the model on the fake data and the real data,

1. Is there a formal or rigorous definition of "similarity" that makes sense in this case? I certainly know a dissimilar data set when I see one, but it's hard to quantify exactly how I know.
2. Is there a straightforward way to generate an IID dataset from a non-IID data set that otherwise preserves some structure from the joint distribution of features?
3. Is this an X-Y problem? Is there a better way to evaluate the effect of data dependence on my estimates?

edit:

4. For a purely predictive task, does non-IID data even make a difference as long as the cross-validation procedure is constructed correctly? [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22411/36229) suggests the answer is "no"

Comment: Elaborate more on why your data isn't IID? and what IID data might look like?

Comment: So you have negative correlations within clusters?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yes

Comment: You could try keeping the same data set, but re-assign the class values $(Y_k)$ independently at random (having the same overall proportion of $Y_k = 1$). You could run this analysis many times and see what changes. I've used a similar approach in a different problem, but it may not work here.

Comment: General: What is the classification? Question 1: What do you mean by similarity, e.g. having the same pdf? Q2: I don't understand what you mean. Q3: it might be, but I again I don't understand the example. In bullet point 4 it becomes clear, that two things are mixed: correlation (read as: non-independence) and generalization power are not really related. In other words: if there is correlation in your input/training data, then this does not mean that you're result/prediction quality is worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have data that is non-IID, and I want to estimate if the dependence is bad enough that it will have a **noticeable effect** on a fitted classifier. I don't think the exact **model type will matter** in this case, but for argument's sake let's say I'm using elastic-net logistic regression.

[On the importance of the i.i.d. assumption in statistical learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213464/on-the-importance-of-the-i-i-d-assumption-in-statistical-learning)

[Regularized Logistic Regression: Lasso vs. Ridge vs. Elastic Net](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297576/regularized-logistic-regression-lasso-vs-ridge-vs-elastic-net)

[Predictive Modeling - Should we care about mixed modeling?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22407/predictive-modeling-should-we-care-about-mixed-modeling)

> Ideally, I would like to be able to compare the fitted model from the non-IID data set to a "comparable" or "similar" IID data set. So I'm thinking I could just simulate such a data set, fit the model on the fake data and the real data,
>
> 1. Is there a formal or rigorous definition of "similarity" that makes sense in this case? I certainly know a dissimilar data set when I see one, but it's hard to quantify exactly how I know.

An **R** software library can help, consider: "[Statistical Patterns in Genomic Sequences](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spgs/index.html)" by [Hart](http://www.cmm.uchile.cl/?cmm_people=andrew-hart) and [Martínez](http://www.cmm.uchile.cl/?cmm_people=servet-martinez) which could be extended to work with arbitrary symbolic sequences, not only DNA sequences.

It features easy to use functions:

- [diid.disturbance](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spgs/versions/1.0-1/topics/diid.disturbance) - Construct feasible Random Noise Generating a Bernoulli Process

  Produces a sequence of random noise which would generate an observed sequence of finite symbols provided that the sequence of symbols results from a Bernoulli process.
- [diid.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spgs/versions/1.0-1/topics/diid.test) - A Test for a Bernoulli Scheme (IID Sequence)

  Tests whether or not a data series constitutes a Bernoulli scheme, that is, an independent and identically distributed (IID) sequence of symbols, by inferring the sequence of IID U(0,1) random noise that might have generated it.

  ```
  Category       Function           Test
  Uniformity     ks.unif.test       Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for uniform$(0,1)$ data
                 chisq.unif.test    Pearson’s chi-squared test for discrete uniform data,
  Independence   lb.test            Ljung-Box $Q$ test for uncorrelated data
                 diffsign.test      signed difference test of independence
                 turningpoint.test  turning point test of independence
                 rank.test          rank test of independence
  ```

Search for a library that exactly meets your requirements or modify one that nearly does.

Also check out the NIST SP [800-22 Statistical Tests](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Random-Bit-Generation/Documentation-and-Software/Guide-to-the-Statistical-Tests) which can be used to [test your data](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_use_the_NIST_test_suite_for_a_randomness_test_of_a_sequence_in_ubuntu).

> 2. Is there a straightforward way to generate an IID dataset from a non-IID data set that otherwise preserves some structure from the joint distribution of features?

Create something like a [k-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-distribution) by [compounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution) some existing distributions to meet your requirements. Use something like [DistributionFitTest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) to check the generated [IID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables).

> 3. Is this an X-Y problem? Is there a better way to evaluate the effect of data dependence on my estimates?

A tiny bit [XY](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), maybe; you've waited a year and a half for an answer, even Tweeted it. You made a minor edit. If I don't get an answer in less than a week I make certain to check if I missed something. You've been asked a few questions and answered one. I have no complaints or questions ...

Test with both (non-IID, IID) generated random models (easy with the software suggested above, though probably more *power* in a different package), your own data, and both. Create a set of "[Ensemble Algorithms](https://machinelearningmastery.com/a-tour-of-machine-learning-algorithms/)" that don't blow up.

> 4. For a purely predictive task, does non-IID data even make a difference as long as the cross-validation procedure is constructed correctly? This answer suggests the answer is "no": [Predictive Modeling - Should we care about mixed modeling?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22411/36229).

The answer requested further information and links, further it was not an absolute "no".

---

See also:

"[Choosing the Correct Statistical Test](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/whatstat/)" (Derived from [Dr. Leeper's work](https://web.archive.org/web/20160912172741/http://bama.ua.edu:80/~jleeper/627/choosestat.html)) - General guidelines for choosing a statistical analysis and links showing how-to using SAS, Stata, SPSS and R.

[Choosing a statistical test](https://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1790/), [Data Analysis Resource Center](https://www.graphpad.com/data-analysis-resource-center/), and [GraphPad Analysis Checklist](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/statistics/index.htm?analysis_checklists2.htm).

<sub><sub>I might have time to return for another edit and improve this answer.</sub></sub>

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to get. I appreciate you taking the time to read between the lines a bit; I struggled to express what I wanted clearly at the time, and even now reading over the question i can see what's wrong with it but I'm not certain how to fix it. I'm going to let this bounty expire so I can award you a bigger one.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. You already have one, the next one is coming once the 24 hour window passses.